# How can I get all links of a website using the Mechanize gem?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How can i get all links of a website using ruby Mechanize gem? 
Does Mechanize can do like Anemone gem:

```
Anemone.crawl("https://www.google.com.vn/") do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do |page|
    puts page.url
  end
end
```

I'm newbie in web crawler. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask a more general question about the tools for scraping in Ruby, I'm interested in the answer, too.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Thank for answering me. Because Anemone is no longer being developed. So i want to change using Mechanize to crawl.

Comment: I didn't answer, I only commented. Maybe there are other tools than just Mechanize. I would go for a more general question.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple with Mechanize, and I suggest you to read the documentation. You can start with [Ruby BastardBook](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/mechanize/).

To get all links from a page with Mechanize try this:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://example.com")
page.links.each {|link| puts "#{link.text} => #{link.href}"}
```

The code is clear I think. `page` is a Mechanize::Page object that stores the whole content of the retrieved page. Mechanize::Page has the `links` method.

Mechanize is very powerful, but remember that if you want to do scraping without any interaction with the website use Nokogiri. Mechanize uses Nokogiri to scrap the web, so for scraping only use Nokogiri.

Comment: Thank you @monktools. Mechanize is very good for interaction web content. But, it don't use for get multi levels links of a website.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't scrape sites, it's a HTML/XML parser; To scrape you'll need to retrieve the content using a HTTP client, typically that'd be OpenURI but many others exist. Mechanize has many helper methods that Nokogiri doesn't have but Nokogiri's strength is that it's more flexible and lets us manipulate a page or extract information from it that we can't get from Mechanize directly.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph, what sort of interaction is required by Mechanize?